# Automatically call controller method and generate partial view. How?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, razor

I want to automatically generate a list in a partial view.

**_Layout.cshtml**

`@Html.Partial("../Transaction/_Transaction")`

**TransactionController**

```
public JsonResult transactionlist()
        {
            List<Transaction> TransactionList = new List<Transaction>().ToList();
            string Usercache = MemoryCache.Default[User.Identity.Name] as string;

            int UsercacheID = Convert.ToInt32(Usercache);
            if (Usercache == null)
            {
                int UserID = (from a in db.UserProfiles
                              where a.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                              select a.UserId).First();
                UsercacheID = UserID;
                MemoryCache.Default[User.Identity.Name] = UsercacheID.ToString();
            }
            var Account = (from a in db.UserAccount
                           where a.UserId == UsercacheID
                           select a).First();

            var DBTransaction = from a in db.Transaction
                                where a.AccountId == Account.AccountId
                                select a;

            var DBTransactionList = DBTransaction.ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < DBTransactionList.Count; i++)
            {
                TransactionList.Add(DBTransactionList[i]);
            }
            ViewBag.acountsaldo = Account.Amount;

            return Json(TransactionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }`
```

How should my `_Transaction.cshtml` be coded to make a simple list without submit buttons etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to have a page return a list of items and feed them into your partial.

```
function ActionResult GetMainTransactionView()
{
  List<Transaction> transactions=GetTransactions();
  return PartialView("TransactionIndex",transactions);
}
```

TransactionIndex.cshtml

```
@model List<Transaction>
@Html.Partial("../Transaction/_Transaction",model)
```

Main.chtml

```
<a id="transactionLink" href='@Url.Action("GetMainTransactionView","Transaction")'/>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should call your controller action and have it return your partial view. Also, use a view model instead of viewbag.

Layout or parent view/partial view:

```
@Html.Action("Transaction", "YourController")
```

Partial view:

```
@model TransactionModel
@foreach (Transaction transaction in Model.TransactionList) {
    // Do something with your transaction here - print the name of it or whatever
}
```

View Model:

```
public class TransactionModel {
    public IEnumerable<Transaction> TransactionList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class YourController
{
    public ActionResult Transaction()
        {
            List<Transaction> transactionList = new List<Transaction>().ToList();
            // Your logic here to populate transaction list
            TransactionModel model = new TransactionModel();
            model.TransactionList = transactionList;

            return PartialView("_Transaction", model);
        }
}
```